# Что делать если при make:controller возникает ошибка

Tags: laravel, controller

Ошибка - `In RouteAction.php line 89: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\]`, что делать? Команда - `php artisan make:controller SearchAnimal`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать роут сначала:

файл - routes/web.php

```
Route::get('search-animal', [
    'as' => 'search.animal',
    'uses' => 'SearchAnimal@index'
]);
```